# Complexity problem reduction?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, complexity-classes

Let say A and B are two decesion problems where A $\le$ B polinomial reduction is true.

Is this : **A̅ $\le$ B̅** also true?

If so, can you show an exemple, if not why?

Comment: Have you tried to prove it? Where did you get stuck?